# Use list without using foreach clause

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a list from a query expression and I want to use the values in it but I don't want to use foreach because if it finds the right value, I dont want it looping again.

```
var partnerProduct = GetPartnerProducts();
var duesproductP = partnerProduct.ToList();
foreach (var c in duesproductP)
{
     //I wont include all the code in between but there are 3 if clauses
}
```

I cant use SingleOrDefault because there is more than one value and I cannot use firstordefault because then it will just give me the first value it finds for all of the clauses I have in between. On my other ones I had criteria where I could sort it like this:

```
 var duesproductsB = sectionB.Where(o => o.capg_MinCriteria.Value <= dues).ToList().OrderByDescending(o => o.capg_MaxCriteria).FirstOrDefault();
```

but now I can't because there is no min or max and the only values returned are the price and Id. It works for the first option and the last option but not the second. The second if clause doesn't work because it keeps looping and assumes the wrong answer. Keep in mind GetPartnerProducts() is a query expression

Comment: Keep in mind I don't have dues or min and max values

Comment: So you're saying you have 3 conditions that can be met by different rows, and you want to stop when all 3 conditions are met?

Comment: I'm not clear on why you can't write `.FirstOrDefault(it => condition1(it) && condition2(it))`  That sounds functionally identical to a `foreach` and a `break`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply check if the value is what you expect and then break out of the loop? Or am I not understanding something correctly?

Comment: It works when I debug and step through but its not displaying the correct values. That would be another question that I need to go through but Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't want to use foreach because if it finds the right value,
>   I dont want it looping again.

If I understand correctly, what you want is to exit the foreach loop without completing the loop for the whole list.

You can do something like this:

```
 foreach (var c in duesproductP)
            {
                 if(somecondition_met)
                    break; //this will exit the for loop
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

just `break` once your conditions are met:

```
List<bool> conditionsFound = new List<bool> {false,false,false};
foreach (var c in duesproductP)
{
     if(condition1)
     {
         // do something
         conditionsFound[0] = true;
     }
     if(condition2)
     {
         // do something
         conditionsFound[1] = true;
     }
     if(condition3)
     {
         // do something
         conditionsFound[2] = true;
     }

     if(conditionsFound.All())
         break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you also want to avoid the use of break; simply put a return statement when the condition met.

Comment: the problem with return in c# is that it will end the condition but not the loop.